# C# - When I use task::wait() method it throwing the exception

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, task, wait

I programming Windows Store App, and I have following problem.
I use this code to record the array of numbers to a file:

```
auto item = KnownFolders::PicturesLibrary;
task<StorageFile^> getFileTask(item->CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting));
getFileTask.then([=](StorageFile^ storageFile)
{
    return storageFile->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::ReadWrite);
}).then([](IRandomAccessStream^ m_istream)mutable
{
    unsigned char a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto arr = ref new Array<unsigned char>(a, sizeof(a));
    auto outs = m_istream->GetOutputStreamAt(0);
    auto dw = ref new DataWriter(outs);
    dw->WriteBytes(arr);
    return dw->StoreAsync();
}).wait();
```

Code is successfully compiled, but it provide an error:
MyTest.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
And it point to `_REPORT_PPLTASK_UNOBSERVED_EXCEPTION();` line, that be found in `ppltasks.h`.

If I use `.then([](DataWriterStoreOperation^){})` instead `.wait()`, My application don't compile with this error:

```
error C2338: incorrect parameter type for the callable object in 'then'; 
consider _ExpectedParameterType or task<_ExpectedParameterType> (see below).
```

Why is that? I using VS2013. Please help me.

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem, you should post it as an answer with an explanation.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but I still cannot do it, because my reputation is less 10.

Answer (score 2):

**I found the solution of this problem!!!
Right code:**

```
unsigned char a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
auto arr = ref new Array<unsigned char>(a, sizeof(a));
auto m_istream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
auto outs = m_istream->GetOutputStreamAt(0);
auto dw = ref new DataWriter(outs);
dw->WriteBytes(arr);
task<unsigned int>(dw->StoreAsync()).then([=](unsigned int)
{
    return item->CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);
}).then([=](StorageFile^ storageFile)
{
    return storageFile->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::ReadWrite);
}).then([=](IRandomAccessStream^ new_stream)
{
    return RandomAccessStream::CopyAsync(m_istream->GetInputStreamAt(0), new_stream->GetOutputStreamAt(0));
}).then([=](UINT64 copiedBytes)
{
    return;
});
```